# textbox value captured with event listener lags

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my goal: I want to have a textbox that when I type into it, it captures what I have *just* typed so I can print it in the console.

I thought this should be easy but I'm having a problem. If I type something in the textbox, like "I'm typing in the textbox" then in the console will be printed "I'm typing in the textbo". It's always one character behind.

Why is that? How can I get it to print what I've *just* typed?

Here is the code:

```
<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="message"></textarea><br>
</body>

<script>
var messageEl = document.getElementById("message");
messageEl.addEventListener("keypress", functionGetMessage);

function functionGetMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  console.log("message:" + message);
};
</script>
```

Also, I have no idea if my title is appropriate.

Comment: *"Why is that?"* - Because in your `keypress` handler it is still possible to cancel the event's default behaviour, in which case the current keypress wouldn't change the value. Try `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

Comment: this is very cool. does your explanation refer to a quirk of javacript or is there a sophisticated reasoning behind that behavior?

Comment: It's not a quirk, it's on purpose. I already mentioned the reasoning. Many event handlers (including keypress) allow you to cancel the current event. If you cancel a keypress then logically that keypress should not update the element's value. Therefore within the keypress event handler the value appears as it was before the keypress. You can tell which key was just pressed by checking properties of the `event` object passed to your handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input` event to get current `.value` of `<input>` element.

```html
<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="message"></textarea><br>
</body>

<script>
var messageEl = document.getElementById("message");
messageEl.addEventListener("input", functionGetMessage);

function functionGetMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  console.log("message:" + message);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var messageEl = document.getElementById("message");
messageEl.addEventListener("keyup", functionGetMessage);

function functionGetMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  console.log("message:" + message);
};
```

```html
<input id="message">
```

Use Keyup event instead of keypress. Or you can use input